# How to call an atom package?

Tags: github, atom-editor

I installed the [atom-runner package](https://github.com/lsegal/atom-runner). I want to create a custom command to execute from the palette to save the current file and then execute the runner. Getting the editor and saving the file works.

`runner:run` fails as does `AtomRunner.run()`

`atom.workspaceView.command 'MyEntry:runner', ->
  editor = atom.workspace.getActiveEditor()
  editor.save()
  runner:run`

Comment: Maybe you need a declaration as in https://github.com/lsegal/atom-runner/blob/170f2291e31c364441c55308155e64b744fbb0c2/spec/atom-runner-spec.coffee#L1 `AtomRunner = require '../lib/runner'`? What is the error message when failing to execute the `runner:run` part?

Comment: Thanks, that got me further. I'm new to coffee script. I tried a few ways to `new` up the AtomRunner and call .run but not luck.

Looks like someone did a PR in the runner and added `editor.save()` directly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To call a Command Palette command from code, you can use `atom.workspaceView.trigger` and give it the name of the command as a string. For example:

```
atom.workspaceView.command 'custom:runner', ->
  editor = atom.workspace.getActiveEditor()
  editor.save()
  atom.workspaceView.trigger 'runner:run'
```

I changed the name of your custom command to `custom:runner` to fit in with the conventions of command naming in Atom and the conventions we've been using in the Atom community for simple commands in one's `init.coffee`. If you wanted to retain the use of "my entry" as the package name (or anything else that has two words in it), I'd recommend formatting it as `my-entry:runner`.

Answer (score 3):

I found that with version 1.9.x the last line of the accepted answer did not work:

```
atom.workspaceView.trigger 'runner:run'
```

After some [searching](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-trigger-a-command-from-plugin-code/9990/3), found that this did:

```
editorView = atom.views.getView(editor)
atom.commands.dispatch(editorView, 'runner:run')
```

Comment: Also `getActiveEditor()` doesn't seem to work anymore. To get the `editor` CofeeScript: `editor = atom.workspace.getActivePaneItem() ? atom.workspace`
Javascript: `editor = atom.workspace.getActivePaneItem() ? atom.workspace.getActivePaneItem() : atom.workspace`

Comment: `editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()` worked for me.